# Angular/Node.js, what's the ports when deployed?

Tags: node.js, angular

I am currently building an app with Angular and NodeJS. On a development environment, it's quite easy, Angular is on port 4200 and I fetch response from Node.js which is on port 3001, for example:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:3001/api/series').subscribe(data => {
    this.data.push(data);
    console.log(this.data);
    }, error => console.error(error));
  }
```

But how does it work when I will want to deploy it on a domain, let's say "https://example.com"?

Comment: It depends how exactly you're going to deploy this. Maybe the client will be able to use _relative_ routes, in which case you can use a dev proxy to replicate this locally. Or maybe it will need configuration to tell it where to look in different environments (which I'd [recommend](https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2020/Sep/19/spa-config.html) providing at runtime, not using Angular's environment feature at build time). Most likely you won't use ports at all outside of localhost, you'd just make the request to `https://example.com/api/series`.

Comment: Digital ocean has some decent guides for deployment. So if you use the notejs part you will run it with something like pm2 and reverse proxy from something like apache or nginx. So locally it will run with default ports. but when with the settings from (nginx/apache) will then point to the nodejs instance. from outside it would be port 80 for http and 443 for https. internally on the server it will use localhost:{default ports} unless specified differently.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

If it's https, it's going to be port 443. If it's http, it will be port 80.

This is a convention, but it's almost always followed. If anyone doesn't believe me, just open inspect element and go to any website. Check the network log.

- Google: 142.250.217.68:443
- Stack overflow: 151.101.1.69:443
- literally example.com: 93.184.216.34:443
- Reddit: 151.101.1.140:443

Note: this is fundamentally different from the port that might actually get contacted on the physical box running the code. For example: you get google by going to 142.250.217.68:443. This address represents tons of machines, and your request will get routed to one of them. Each machine has it's own local ip address and port, which can be literally anything. So your code might be hosted on 192.168.1.254:1234 within a datacenters local network, but users will still use [some ip]:443 to get to your website.

Edit based on feedback from jonrsharpe: You absolutely do not need to specify these ports. You can just send requests to https://example.com/ and your server will get them. All the port nonsense pretty much gets taken care of by other people

Comment: This isn't _inaccurate_, as such, but it's not actually going to help the OP connect their frontend and backend. Yes 80 and 443 are the default ports for HTTP and HTTPS respectively, but _because of that_ you very rarely write them explicitly.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I mean, I agree that you don't need to specify the port, but OP literally asked what the port was. I feel like telling him "you don't need it" is sort of dodging the question.

Comment: That is literally what they asked, but you have to be aware of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248731).

Comment: @jonrsharpe I appreciate the insight, and you make a good point. I have updated my answer to explain that the ports are unnecessary.  I do still think it's worth explaining what's going on with the ports, but you are quite right that the solution to his problem is simply to ignore them.